# Magento 2 - Call to a member function addAttributeToFilter() on null

Tags: magento2, product, category, error, phtml

I am working on a module for a customer that is designed to generate a category link to the main artist page for the product. I've created a module that's designed to get the category IDs of the artist categories then the categories of the current product. Afterwards, it compares the arrays for a matching value then gets the category name and URL from the matching category ID value.

But I'm getting this instead:
`Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addAttributeToFilter() on null`

Here's the code for the block:

```
<?php
namespace Custom\ArtistLink\Block;

class ArtistLink extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_catalogLayer;
    protected $_categoryHelper;
    protected $_outputHelper;
    protected $_dataHelper;
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_categoryRepository;
    
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $outputHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $dataHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $outputHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->_outputHelper = $outputHelper;
        $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    /**
     * Get Artist category productCategories
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection or array
     */
    public function getArtistCategories()
    {
        $artistCategoryId = '20';
        $artistParent = $this->_categoryRepository->get($artistCategoryId);
        $artistSubcats = $artistParent->getChildrenCategories();
        return $artistSubcats;
    }

    /**
     * Get product category collection
     *
     * @param bool $isActive
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection or array
     */
    public function getProductCategories($isActive = true)
    {
        $productCategories = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $productCategories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        
        if ($isActive) {
            $productCategories->addIsActiveFilter();
        }
        
        return $productCategories;
    }

    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    }
        
    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {  
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }
    
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentCategory()->getIdentities();
    }
}
```

And the PHTML;

```
<?php
$parentCategory = $block->getParentCategoryId();
$artistCategories = $block->getArtistCategories();
//$product = $block->getCurrentProduct();
$prodId = 2832;
$product = $block->getProductById($prodId);

$catIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
$productCategories = $block->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $catIds);

$categoryMatch = array_intersect($artistCategories, $productCategories);
?>

<div>
product id: <?php echo $prodId; ?>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div>
artist categories:<br />
<?php echo $artistCategories; ?>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div>
product categories:<br />
<?php echo $catIds; ?>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div>
category collection:<br />
<?php echo $productCategories; ?>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div>
array match:<br />
<?php echo $categoryMatch; ?>
</div>
```

It's a test phtml file meant to verify the values are displayed as expected.

This is where it fails:
`$productCategories = $block->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $catIds);`
That returns null and I get why, but not sure what I need to do to fix it.
`$catIds = $product->getCategoryIds();` returns null but I'm not sure why... or where I went wrong.

I used this tutorial to help me build things out a bit: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-categories-specific-product-magento-2.html.

After correcting the template to use the right function, I am now getting the following:
`Warning: array_intersect(): Argument #1 is not an array`
Which means `$artistCategories` isn't an array.

```
    public function getArtistCategories()
    {
        $artistCategoryId = '20';
        $artistParent = $this->_categoryRepository->get($artistCategoryId);
        $artistSubcats = $artistParent->getChildrenCategories();
        return $artistSubcats;
    }
```

is supposed to get the categories as an array, but I'm not sure what it's being returned as. Can I cast to an array?

Answer (score 1):

Your class "ArtistLink" does not have the function "getCategoryCollection".

Comment: That was a stupid on my part but I updated my question with more information.